# ListView changes colors on 2.x

Tags: android, android-listview, actionbarsherlock, simpleadapter

I have a simple demo app with just one listActivity and I'm using actionBarSherlock.

My styles.xml is:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock"></style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#388E8E</item>
        <item name="background">#388E8E</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

This style gives me a blue actionbar in 2.x and 3.x with white text in the action bar and a white background on my activity. Looks perfect on Android 2.x and 4.x. The problem is that in 2.x when I scroll, I get a black background. I'm currently using a SimpleAdapter:

```
int[] ids = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, aList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, from, ids);
```

Any ideas on how to stop this from happening?

Comment: Refers following links.



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792976/android-listview-produces-black-highlighting-over-text-when-scrolling-how-to-st
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909686/fragment-inside-scrollview-gives-black-background-flickering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi @EGHDK it is your list page problem. append android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" in your listView node. example
`<ListView
android:id="@+id/list"`
`android:layout_width="match_parent"`
`android:layout_height="match_parent"`
`android:layout_gravity="start"`
`android:background="@color/somecolor"`
`android:divider="@android:color/transparent"`
`android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />`